# Convert a list to a matrix

Tags: python

I want to convert a list with numbers to a matrix. This is my code:

```
   def converttomtx(mylist, rows, columns):
       mtx = []
       for r in range(rows):
           lrow = []
           for c in range(columns):
               lrow.append(mylist[rows * r + c])
           mtx.append(lrow)
       return mtx
```

Assuming I use the following list:
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

The code works if I set the rows to 3 and columns to 4, but when I set rows to 4 and columns to 3 then it throws an error that the list index is out of range. I cannot see why. The same happens when I use 2x6 and 6x2, 2x6 works but 6x2 doesn't.

Comment: The error has told you what might be wrong. Do you check the index of `mylist`?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to approach it. Why and how should I check the index?

Comment: How to check? - `print` the index. Maybe you could read the material on [row-major/column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), which may help you understand the index transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you are calculating the index of the list item to be inserted in the matrix, `rows * r + c` would be more than 11 if rows = 6 for example, so it should be `columns * r + c` or `rows * c + r`

You can try printing `columns * r + c` and `rows * r + c` in your for loop for understanding the bug in your original solution.

Here's the updated code -

```
def converttomtx(mylist, rows, columns):
   mtx = []
   for r in range(rows):
       lrow = []
       for c in range(columns):
           lrow.append(mylist[columns * r + c])  # updated
       mtx.append(lrow)
   return mtx

print(converttomtx([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 2, 6))
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

For

```
print(converttomtx([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 6, 2))
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the robust `numpy` library for any type of list [reshaping](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), for example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> li = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> li = np.array(li) # convert to an ndarray

>>> li.reshape(2, 6)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> li.reshape(6, 2)
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
```

Let's assume, you don't know any of the dimensions you can also use: `li.reshape(3, -1)` which will compute the dimension for you.

```py
>>> li.reshape(3, -1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`mylist[rows * r + c]` should be `mylist[columns * r + c]` as `columns` is the correct offset in `mylist`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
def l2m(mylist, rows, cols):
    if len(mylist) != rows * cols:
        print('wrong shape')
        return
    return [mylist[row*cols:(row+1)*cols] for row in range(rows)]


mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

print(l2m(mylist, 12, 1))
print(l2m(mylist, 3, 4))
print(l2m(mylist, 9, 3)
```

This returns:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
wrong shape
None
```

Answer (score 0):

You just used the *wrong formula for index* in line 6.

Instead of `mylist[rows * r + c]`

It should be `mylist[columns * r + c]`

after this your code would look like:

```
def converttomtx(mylist, rows, columns):
       mtx = []
       for r in range(rows):
           lrow = []
           for c in range(columns):
               lrow.append(mylist[columns * r + c])
           mtx.append(lrow)
       return mtx
```